# Why vbscript email alert does not pick the column in the sql query given?

Tags: sql, vbscript

Below is the SQL query I have in my vbscript file.

---

```
with temp as (
    select distinct user_id,
           user_email_addr,
           proj_nm 
    from test_table1 
    where user_enabled_ind='Y' 
          and user_extrl <> 'Y'
          and datediff(dd,user_ts,getdate()) between 83 and 90 
          and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1' 
          and user_id <>'testproject2'
) SELECT Name=p1.user_id,
         Address=p1.user_email_addr, 
         (SELECT proj_nm + ', ' 
          FROM temp p2 
          WHERE p2.user_id = p1.user_id 
          ORDER BY proj_nm FOR XML PATH('')) AS Project 
  FROM temp p1 
  GROUP BY user_id,user_email_addr;
```

---

When I run this query, I get result something like this:

---

```
Name   Address         Project
abc1   abc1@xyz.com    Apple,Mango
abc2   abc2@xyz.com    Apple,Banana,Mango
abc3   abc3@xyz.com    Mango
```

---

As per my vbscript, it is supposed to send email with project in the email body. But, the email alert is breaking where I put the project field.

Please help.

VbScript:

---

```
option explicit

const connstr = "DSN=DSN_APP"

dim connexion, recordset, record
dim sqltxt

sqltxt = "with temp as (select distinct user_id,user_email_addr,proj_nm from test_table1 where user_enabled_ind='Y' and user_extrl <> 'Y'and datediff(dd,user_ts,getdate()) between 83 and 90 and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1' and user_id <>'testproject2') SELECT Name=p1.user_id,Address=p1.user_email_addr, (SELECT proj_nm + ', ' FROM temp p2 WHERE p2.user_id = p1.user_id ORDER BY proj_nm FOR XML PATH('')) AS Project FROM temp p1 GROUP BY user_id,user_email_addr;"

set connexion = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set recordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connexion.Open connstr
recordset.Open sqltxt, connexion

if recordset.Eof then
   wscript.Echo "The result is empty."
else
  do until recordset.Eof
     if not IsNull(recordset("address")) then
        SendMail recordset("name"), recordset("address"), recordset("project")
     end if 
     recordset.MoveNext
  loop
end if

recordset.Close
connexion.Close


function SendMail(TheName, TheAddress, TheProjectList)
  dim strTable1, strTable2, strTable3, strTable4
  dim objMessage

rem override TheAddress for testing purpose
rem TheAddress = "abc@xyz.com"  
  set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

  strTable1 = "<TABLE border=0 width=900><TR><TD align=center bgcolor=#ffab00 nowrap><FONT color='white'><B>~Application Inactive User Account  Notification~</B></FONT></TD></TR></TABLE>"
  strTable1 = strTable1 & "<DIV style=text-align: center;><B><BR>" & FormatDateTime(Date(),1) & "</DIV><BR><BR></B>"

  strTable2 = "<TABLE border=0 width=800><TR><TD align=left borderColor=white>Dear Application user " & "<B>(NT ID: "& TheName & ")," & "</B></TD></TR></TABLE>"
  strTable2 = strTable2 & "<br/>"

  strTable3 = <TABLE border=0 width=800><TR><TD align=left borderColor=white>This is a notification alert to inform you that you will result in deactivation of your id after 5 days. Please login to the following projects:- " & "<B>(" & TheProjectList & ")</B>" & " to become 'Active' again and prevent being disabled." & "</TD></TR></TABLE>"
  strTable3 = strTable3 & "<br/>"

  strTable4 = "<TABLE border=0 width=800><TR><TD align=left borderColor=white><B>Thank You," & "</B></TD></TR></TABLE>"
  strTable4 = strTable4  & "<TABLE border=0 width=800><TR><TD align=left borderColor=white><B>IIS Team" & "</B></TD></TR></TABLE>"

  objMessage.Subject = "Application Inactive User Account Notification" 
  objMessage.From = "IPC Services <informationservices@xyz.com>" 
  objMessage.To = "abc@xyz"
rem put your address for testing purpose
rem objMessage.CC = "abc@xyz.com"
rem objMessage.CC = "test@xyz.com"
  objMessage.TextBody = "***************THIS IS AN AUTO GENERATED MESSAGE. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY.***************" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  objMessage.HTMLBody = strTable1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTable2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTable3 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTable4

  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
 'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "internet1.xyz.com"
 'Server port (typically 25)
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

  objMessage.Send
  set objMessage = Nothing
rem test run output
rem wscript.Echo "TheName=" & TheName & " TheAddress=" & TheAddress

end function
```

---

The above VB script generates an email alert, which breaks at the place where project is called. And the text next to project does not appear in the email alert. Please help.

Comment: Include the actual vbscript that is executing the query and the code that is outputting it to email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in newer versions of VBscript, 'XML PATH' might not support.
So please check the server and version of VBScript compatibility.

In order to achieve this extract name and email through one query and extract project name with another variable to store comma separated project names.